# php email management and Event management

Tags: php, open-source, integration

I have a client that has a list of several thousand email addresses (and their personal info). If they are holding an event in a particular city, they want to send an email to "everyone in these cities with these parameters". They would like to keep track of who attends each event, let people unsubscribe, but not loose their data, track other attributes about each person over time, etc.

The main company site is in Drupal, but this project can use any platform. Any suggestions about php software that can be customized to do this?

Comment: Not sure why I would get a down-vote for the question as I am asking about specific functionality that I was having a hard time finding.

Comment: OK, I get that this is off topic for the reasons listed above, but why would I keep getting down votes that affect my reputation? Can I delete the question somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there is lots of software to do this, but I was looking for any advice someone might have to help me narrow down the search because there are so many scripts to test.

In this case, I settled on CiviCRM, which has both a drupal and a wordpress integration and does everything that I needed, specifically the ability to record lots of meta data about the individuals in the database and then to segment that data to use for sending email.

https://civicrm.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is heaps of software to do this. You will have to get the data into a form that can be imported into a database though like mysql.

Wordpress has lots of plugins that can import mailing lists and news letters.

Once the data is in a database table then you could also write your own quite easily. If you aren't a coder though wordpress plugins or something similar might be the way to go.

Also, checkout mailchimp and services like that.

p.s. if you send several thousands emails you will probably get black listed :P